# Getting error while install plugins in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, maven-install-plugin, jenkins-git-plugin

I was trying to install Jenkins in local and while installing the Plugin such as GIT in Manage Plugin am getting error as following:

```
"sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:145)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
```

Comment: I have re installed different version of java and tries again and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add the git pub cert to your cacerts file wherever your jdk is installed.

Comment: Hi I am new to this and i tried to perform as you mention with reference from https://youtu.be/RpVg7IbBZbc but still facing same issue  @Vizzyy